# Como exibir os valores de um JSON via PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, json

Como posso exibir os valores de um JSON via echo em PHP,
Estou usando o código abaixo para receber o JSON do site dos Correios

```
    $json_file = file_get_contents("http://cep.correiocontrol.com.br/$cep.json");

    $json_str = json_decode($json_file, true);
    //echo "$json_str";
```

Esse JSON tem os seguintes valores:

```
{"bairro": "Jangurussu", "logradouro": "Rua 22", "cep": "60876470", "uf": "CE", "localidade": "Fortaleza"}
```

Há alguma forma de eu usar o echo para exibir esses valores?

Ex.

```
echo "Bairro: $bairro";
echo "Logradouro: $logradouro";
echo "CEP: $cep";
echo "UF: $uf";
echo "Localidade: $localidade";
```

Resultado:

Bairro: Jangurussu

Logradouro: Rua 22

CEP:60876470

UF:CE

Localidade:Fortaleza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depois de usares `$json_str = json_decode($json_file, true);` a tua array (agora associativa) vai ficar assim:

```
array(5) 
{ 

    ["bairro"]=> string(10) "Jangurussu" 
    ["logradouro"]=> string(6) "Rua 22" 
    ["cep"]=> string(8) "60876470" 
    ["uf"]=> string(2) "CE" 
    ["localidade"]=> string(9) "Fortaleza" 

}
```

então podes usar o echo para imprimir esses valores. Se quiseres fazer dentro de um loop podes fazer assim:

```
foreach ($json_str as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value<br />\n"; // aqui podes colocar mais HTML se quiseres
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://ideone.com/6kXUT2

Se quiseres mapear essas chaves/keys então sugiro teres outra array para dar o nome com caixa alta.

Por exemplo:

```
$titulos = array("bairro"=>"Bairro", "logradouro"=>"Logradouro", "cep"=>"CEP", "uf"=>"UF",  "localidade"=>"Localidade");
```

e aí podes fazer assim:

```
foreach ($json_str as $key => $value) {
    echo "$titulos[$key]: $value<br />\n"; // aqui podes colocar mais HTML se quiseres
}
```