# Como extrair um valor de um retorno JSON

Tags: php, json, array

Eu tenho o seguinte JSON

```
{
  "cep": "11702-705",
  "logradouro": "Avenida Presidente Castelo Branco",
  "complemento": "de 4224 a 4800 - lado par",
  "bairro": "Aviação",
  "localidade": "Praia Grande",
  "uf": "SP",
  "unidade": "",
  "ibge": "3541000",
  "gia": "5587"
}
```

e quero ter apenas o valor de "uf". Como fazer?

Comment: Está usando Jquery?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Receber dados de JSON externo por PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4410/receber-dados-de-json-externo-por-php), [json_decode($data) PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211884), [Como exibir os valores de um JSON via PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45710), [Como Exibir varios valores de um JSON em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49421)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize a função `json_decode`. Essa função irá te retornar um `objeto` ou um `array`, por exemplo:

```
<?php

$json = <<<JSON
{
  "cep": "11702-705",
  "logradouro": "Avenida Presidente Castelo Branco",
  "complemento": "de 4224 a 4800 - lado par",
  "bairro": "Aviação",
  "localidade": "Praia Grande",
  "uf": "SP",
  "unidade": "",
  "ibge": "3541000",
  "gia": "5587"
}
JSON;

/* Retorna um objeto */
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->uf;

/* Retorna um array */
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data["uf"];
```